# Estimate the rate of height growth of humans in km/ hr?

Tags: math, puzzle

Someone asked me this question during an interview. How would you go about this? This is not a random BS question but has good math behind it. The profile was for an analytic position so they wanted someone with good math skills. I couldn't really figure out a good way of calculating this.

Here is some data I collected after the interview which might be helpful:

Height growth depends mainly on genetic factors, diet, standard of life etc. Human grow rate  is fastest at birth rapidly declining between  0 & 2, tapering to a slowly declining rate & then a rapid rise at puberty say 13 which gives you a second maxima followed by a steady decline to 0 at roughly age 18.

`You may use this data or make your own assumptions to answer the question.` Also how would you go about answering based on just the title of this question, knowing that you need to demonstrate strong math skills?

Comment: How is this a programming question? http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: The rate of growth (which is already a distance per unit time) would be in distance / time^2? i.e. km / hr^2. But is << 1 IMHO ... and the choice of unit is poor ... like using metres measuring the distances between galaxies ... ?

Comment: At an interview, they're just going to want something like: well, between the ages of 12 and say 18 you're probably going to grow by about half a metre. So, that's 1 meter every 12 years, or 1km every 12000 years, which is 1/(12000*365*24) km/h.  You're just proving you're not thrown by the units, and able to do some vaguely sensible estimation.  Same as the old move Mt Fuji etc..

Comment: @selbie: not at all - anyone with reasonable analytical skills and basic maths should be able to solve this kind of problem - if not then they are probably not cut out for programming (or anything much in the realm of technical jobs)

Answer (score 2):

The units are a red herring: km/hr is misleading when we're talking about something that's more meaningful and intuitive at cm/year.

With that said, you've already cited the maximum rates between zero and two years old and "puberty".  You have to agree on what you're looking for: the maximum value or the overall value?

Since this is an interview question, all you have to do is state your assumptions and give a result.

If an individual reaches their full adult height by age 21 years, and the [average height](http://pediatrics.about.com/cs/growthcharts2/f/avg_ht_male.htm) for a male in the United States is 69.2 inches, the average growth rate is between 3-4 inches per year.   Since 1 inches = 2.54 × 10-5 kilometers, you can see that it's about 7.5e-5 to 10e-5 km/year.  Since 1 year = 8 765.8 hours, I'll leave that final multiplication to you.